Holomorphic function on a quadrant that vanishes on the real line
I'd like to consider a holomorphic function $f(z)$ on the 1st quadrant of the complex plane $z\in \mathbb{C}:\Re z>0, \Im z>0$. Suppose that the function vanishes on the real line $f(x)=0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $f$ must be constant?
I found a similar question asked here:
Holomorphic function on a square that vanishes on a side, but I am unable to apply the same logic here.

Are you assuming continuity on the closure?

Yes, I do assume that.

In particular the function is holomorphic on the square $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ and vanishes on one side. If it is constant on the square it must be constant everywhere else.

I will assume that $f$ is continuous on the closure of its domain.
As $f$ is real valued in the real line, by Schwarz's reflection principle we can find some $g$ holomorphic in $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)>0\}$ such that $g(z)=f(z)$ for $z\in\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)>0, \Im(z)>0\}$.
Now, $g$ is holomorphic in the domain $D$ and vanishes in the set $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \Re(z)>0,\Im(z)=0\}$, which clearly has an accumulation point of $D$ (every point in $S$ is an accumulation point of $D$). By the identity theorem, $g\equiv 0$ and thus $f\equiv 0$.
